# Are Plesk server backups useful?

Tags: backup

I'm working for a startup now, and I'm the programmer. Because of our small team size, I'm also handling the server management for now (until we get a dedicated server administrator.) I've never used Plesk before, and the server we're using (a Media Temple Dedicated Virtual server) had it installed when I got here.

One of my first jobs was to set up backups: Plesk was already running it's nightly server-wide backups. I created a small script to dump the web app, it's DBs and any assets, tar them, store them, and then copy them to another small server we have (to backup the backups.)

But, we're constantly running into hard drive space issues because of the Plesk backups. And I'm wondering, are they useful? If I have the web app and all of it's assets, I could easily enough get another server up and running. Do we need to keep running Plesk's backups?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as baking up your data, the plesk backup will also be backing up your configuration, so things like IIS or Apache setup, DNS etc, and the accounts created in plesk.
If it's only you using plesk and your happy to recreate all these things should the server fail, then fine, get rid of them, but if you have customers using plesk as well, or you want to be able to restore you plesk configuration on failure, you should keep them.

That said, if you already backing up your data, you could set plesk backup to just backup config data.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for. I'm going to switch Plesk to just handle config data from now on.